# Clustering into teams of fixed size

Tags: clustering, k-means, partitioning, semi-supervised-learning

There is a particular team-based video game that exposes a ladder of individual ratings for each player that looks like this (player, rating, wins, losses):

- A, 2000, 35, 12
- B, 1900, 41, 19
- C, 1800, 20, 4
- D, 1700, 17, 5
- E, 1700, 30, 19

On each iteration players form teams of certain size (let's say 2) and play against each other. Their individual ratings change based on the outcome of the game (some kind of an ELO system).

**Problem**
Given sequence of those ladders find out which teams participated on each turn.

**Example**
Let's imagine that the next ladder is the following:

- A, 2014, 36, 12
- B, 1875, 41, 20
- C, 1776, 20, 5
- D, 1715, 18, 5
- E, 1700, 30, 19

It is safe to assume that teams that played were {A, D} and {B, C}. Who played vs who is not important, only which players played together in the same team.

**Dimensions**: total number of players ~5000, total players playing on each ladder iteration after grouping them by winners/losers (obviously they can't be in the same team) ~30 .

**What I tried**
My current more or less successful ad-hoc approach was to run lots of K-means with different seeds and pick one clustering that minimizes number of teams of incorrect sizes. That seems to be very crude as a) running K-means with different seeds does not actually yield lots of different results, b) it eliminates tons of valid teams.

It's kind of a unsupervised learning problem because I do not actually know if the algorithm guessed right or wrong, except I can turn it into a supervised learning problem by programmatically generating test ladders and controlling who plays who on each turn.

Thanks for reading this. Would love to hear if there are any known approaches to similar problems I can try.

Comment: Do you have the formula to calculate the rating change after a game (I guess not) ? Can a player play more than one game between one ladder iteration ?

Comment: How is the sequence of ladders structured over time? Does each ladder correspond to a time sample? Or is the ladder structure output according to some discrete event (game start or game end)?

Comment: @steffen I don't have the exact formula, player can play only one game between iterations.

Comment: @vpipkt each ladder corresponds to some moment in time, but there are never 2 games played by any player between ladder updates.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think this is a clustering problem at all.** You may have been using the wrong tool for the problem.

See: clustering algorithms like k-means will try to *force* all your data objects into *k* clusters, minimizing the sum of squared deviations.

But does it make sense in your case to minimize the sum of squared deviations? IMHO, it doesn't.

Instead, you need to choose an approach that uses all your knowledge of the data (which k-means doesn't).

In particular, you may want to break your data into three groups first: players who didn't play, players who won, and players who lost. By doing so, you will effectively eliminate the last two columns, but that is okay.

Then you may want to figure out a derived measure for your score. For example, compute the relative change in score, i.e.
$$ f(x) = \frac{\text{score}_t(x) - \text{score}_{t-1}(x)}{\text{score}_{t-1}(x)}$$

which hopefully makes players much more similar; since I assume the score change depends on the average score of the opponents.

Then, plug in your team size. If you know the teams are always of size 2, find the partitioning of the data into pairs of two player, such that the errors are the smallest. Most likely, you can just sort your data and pair even and odd.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Some of that stuff I already do, I group players by winners/losers on each turn. Then solve the problem separately for each group. The score change alone isn't too distinctive, so knowing that some players tend to play together throughout the season or a week I create a feature vector for each player (rating change, current rating, total wins, total losses, weekly wins, weekly losses, etc) and try to run K-means on those feature vectors representing the players. It's just that K-means being very generic discards too much of my data.

Comment: If only there was some variation of K-means that tries to create clusters of fixed sizes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last paragraph? How do I find such a partition without going through all possible N-player combinations? The k-means is actually used as kind of an optimization technique because that number is just incredibly huge, but it has its own drawbacks.

Comment: There is a k-means variation with equal sizes. But it will break down if you increase k to n/2. Also, it won't scale anymore; k-means is also linear in k, so if you increase k to almost n, you are effectively quadratic. http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SameSizeKMeans
But it's really not useful for your scenario IMHO.

Comment: The approach I outlined used a single point in time. Exploit that you can *sort* this data. You only need to look at neighbors.

Comment: So what is your exact objective: finding which players played *once* together, or which play *frequently* together?

Comment: I want to find a players that played between 2 ladder iterations together, but the information about them playing frequently together can be additional indicator they are playing this turn too.

Comment: Can there be more than one game of the same players between two iterations? If not (or if the case where a player plays in different teams within the same iteration is neglible) then above approach may be helpful, and you could just use frequently-together to post-process the results to improve the overall quality.

Comment: There's only 1 game of each player max between iterations. I'll try and see if it works. Thanks.